# Idiomatic way of calling a jQuery function on a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a Javascript DOM object, what is the most idiomatic way of calling a jQuery function on it? Currently, I am using:

`$('#' + object.id).someFunction()`

However, this doesn't feel quite right. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Thanks - I knew this would be simple, but now I do feel a bit ridiculous for asking the question. I guess that's what happens when you learn to use a library by example instead of actually learning it bottom up from a good book. Oh well! We all have these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
 $(object).someFunction();
```

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/XsKXU/

See [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for reference on the `$` (aka `jQuery`) function

Answer (score 6):

If you have the DOM object, just feed it straight to jQuery.  Like so:

```
var my_div = document.getElementById("my_div");
$(my_div).someFunction();
```